# How to execute a script (e.g. mvnw) as if you were in that directory in the background?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have my application with maven where you can 'cd' to this directory /path/app/execute/. and run 'mvnw' and the app starts fine.

My problem is I want to create a start script in the parent directory here: /path/app/startMyApp.sh.

It's contents are:

```
nohup /path/app/execute/mvnw &
```

My problem is, when I cd to /path/app and run './startMyApp.sh', I am getting:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain

How can I keep my script in the parent directory of the "mvnw" executable, and be able to execute it as if I were in that directory as a background process (nohup) in the script?

Comment: can you please tell us that where is your .mvn file is stored ?

Comment: Home directory. There was a typo in the post, am using mvnw, not mvn. Fixed OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting the difference between "mvnw" and "mvn" in your question, if the crux of your problem is changing directory into /path/app/execute under `nohup`, then:

```
nohup sh -c 'cd /path/app/execute; mvnw' &
```